# Using PC-Lint on project with third party libraries

Tags: c, embedded, pc-lint

I have a project which includes a large third party library and am required to ensure that the project is lint-free. However, the library has several thousand errors.

Modifying the library to remove these is not an option - how would this typically be handled?

Currently, the code is built using Keil uVision and this is where PC-Lint is called from so if this could still be the case that would be best.

Is there a way to specify that these are library files and so should not be analysed?

Thanks.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to just completely skip linting a set of source files?  (Your library isn't a pre-compiled object file, you're compiling from source?)  If you completely skip the files, you may end up with "function not defined" type errors during the global wrap-up...

Comment: Exactly. This is why I do not just exclude the files from the LINT command. Is it possible to include them for this purpose, but also to indicate that their errors should be omitted?

Answer (score 8):

Here is the info from the Gimpel website, I believe that it covers the options you are looking for (bold added for emphasis):

> Lint uses the label of "library" header to designate those headers over which a programmer has no control (such as compiler headers).  By default all #includes from a foreign directory, or enclosed within < > , are considered "library."  **This can be modified through the use of the +libclass option, and further fine-tuned with the  +/-libdir and +/-libh options.  You can then use the -wlib , -elib and -elibsym options to control just those messages being  emitted from library headers.**   Compiler options files distributed with PC-lint usually  contain a -wlib(1) option which limits lint output from library headers to errors only (suppressing warning and informational messages).

You can find more information at the Gimpel site [here](http://www.gimpel.com/html/techfaq.htm).

Also, if I remember correctly, -wlib(0) suppresses all library errors and warnings... as opposed to the -wlib(1) mentioned above.  I will have to double check when I get back to work.  I don't have a copy of the manual with me.

**---EDIT---**

If it is an option, I would place all of the files associated with the library in a different directory.  In Keil, you can go to "Tools->Set-up PC-Lint".  Then add your new directory to the list of "PC-Lint Include Folders".  Your -wlib(0) option should then treat those headers as 'foreign' and not return errors.  Of course, you would have to modify the project settings to compile the library files as well.

**---EDIT2 Added Example---**

Okay, so here is a little test I tried to ensure that my suggestion would work.  I created a project in a directory I named "ex_lib" and named the project **lib_test**.  In "Source Group 1" I created and added the file "main.c":

**main.c**

```
#include <lib_test.h>

int main (void)
{
    uint16_t x = 5;
    uint16_t y = 10;
    uint16_t total1 = 0;
    uint16_t total2 = 0;
    uint16_t total3 = 0;
    uint16_t total4 = 0;


    total1 = add(x,y);
    total2 = sub(x,y);
    total3 = mult(x,y);
    total4 = div(x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

I then created a sub-directory named "library" and created a second project named **library** in that directory.  The library project consisted of the following files "lib_test.h" and "lib_test.c".

**lib_test.h**

```
#ifndef LIB_TEST__
#define LIB_TEST__

#include <stdint.h>

extern uint16_t add(uint16_t x, uint16_t y);
extern uint16_t sub(uint16_t x, uint16_t y);
extern uint16_t mult(uint16_t x, uint16_t y);
extern uint16_t div(uint16_t x, uint16_t y);

#endif /* LIB_TEST__ */
```

**lib_test.c**

```
#include "lib_test.h"

uint16_t add(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    return (x + y);
}

uint16_t sub(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    return (x - y);
}

uint16_t mult(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    return (x * y);
}

uint16_t div(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{
    return (x / y);
}
```

In the **library** project, under "Options for Target 'Target 1'", I selected "Create Library".  I then compiled the **library** project.

After successfully compiling, I went back to the **lib_test** project and right-clicked on "Target1" and selected "Add Group".  I created a group called "Library" and added the previously compiled "library.lib" from the "library" directory to the "Library" group.

Finally, under the options for Target 1 (in the **lib_test** project), I went to the "C/C++" tab and added "library" to the "Include Paths".  I was then able to successfully compile (with some warnings about variables being set but never used) the **lib_test** project.  Under "Tools->Set-up PC-Lint" I added the following:

PC-Lint Include Folders:  C:\Keil_ARM\RV31\INC\ and library\

Lint Executable: C:\Lint\LINT-NT.EXE

Configuration File: C:\Lint\lnt\CO-RV.LNT

I modified the CO-RV.LNT file to verify my Lint results by modifying -wlib().  When I ran Lint with -wlib(0) I received no warnings or errors about my library files.  I then changed -wlib(2) and I received numerous warnings about stdint.h.

This is definitely an oversimplification but it should give you a good starting point.  Also, I received Lint warnings about my variables not being accessed in "main.c" but I expected that.

Comment: I did see this and have tried it - but as far as I can see, it an only be applied to header files - is this wrong?

Comment: I think the key is to ensure that your third party library files are in a 'foreign' directory - then all #includes to their header files would reference that directory.  It may be a bit too cumbersome depending on the size of your project, but it is an option.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed response! I already have all the library files in a dedicated directory. Separating into two projects and using the library file could work, but this breaks the 'Go To Definition Of ..' feature, which is a shame. My concern for completely skipping the files is that I believe a complete project analysis is best (both for use with ALOA and to avoid 'function not defined' errors - so all in all, I would like to keep everything together so that Keil functionality is not broken, but indicate that certain files may contain errors. Is this possible?

Comment: I can see how that would be an issue.  One option may be to lint the library separately.  You shouldn't have any "function not defined" errors with the method above.  I actually use SlickEdit for my code editor because I am often working with different tools/compilers (uVision, VisualDSP++, MPLAB, etc).  So I run PC-Lint and do all of my editing through SlickEdit and handle compiling/debugging dependent upon the platform I am working on.  I am sure that there is a work-around, but you would probably have to play around to get it to work.

Comment: Add: use -e686 option after -wlib(0) to remove warning: Option 'wlib(0)' is suspicious because of ...

Comment: @Borzh I found that I needed to use -e686 *before* -wlib(0) to suppress the error message. I had -wlib(0) in a .lnt file, so I needed to place -e686 either at the top of the .lnt file, or on the commandline before the .lnt file is passed. Adding -e686 to a second .lnt file listed after the first didn't work. Thanks for the lead though! I used this to avoid 686 from messing up my XML output that I feed to SonarQube.

Comment: @PolyTekPatrick Thanks to pointing out this, you are right, -e686 should be _before_ -wlib(0). Struggling with flexelint for SonarQube also led me here :)